# How can I create new empty folders in a directory using names of subfolders of another directory using batch script?

Tags: windows, svn, batch-file, scripting, backup

My main goal is to backup SVN repositories in REPOS folder. Since "svnadmin hotcopy" has to have both source and target folders I need to create new folders in different directory with name of folderName_backup and then copy them using "svnadmin hotcopy". Btw this has to be done in windows batch file. My code for this portion is the following:

```
for /d %%X in (%source%\*) do (
 md %destination%\%%X_backup
 svnadmin hotcopy %%X %destination%\%%X_backup

 )
```

After running this code I get error : The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /b /a:d "%Source%"') do (
    md %destination%\%%G

    svnadmin hotcopy %Source%\%%G %Destination%\%%G 
 )
```

The problem with the old solution was instead of getting folder names in directory it gets subdirectory of the directory. This is why the result was something like `C:\where\the\backup\will\be\C:\where\the\folders\are`

That was the reason that I got error:The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. The script part (works fine) that I have shared with you above in answer tokenize the subdirectory to get the folder name and use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
set "source=c:\where\the\folders\are"
set "destination=c:\where\the\backup\will\be"

for /d %%a in ("%source%\*") do for %%b in ("%destination%\%%~nxa_backup") do (
    if not exist "%%~fb\" md "%%~fb" 
    if exist "%%~fb\" svnadmin hotcopy "%%~fa" "%%~fb"
)
```

`%%~fb` is the full path to the file/folder referenced in `%%b`. The equivalent for `%%~fa`. `%%~nxa` is the name and extension of the file/folder referenced in `%%a`.

The code encloses all paths in quotes to avoid problems with spaces, and test for existence of the folder before creation and backup

You can remove the inner `for %%b` and use the composed target folder in the `md` and `svnadmin` commands (as in your code), but this aditional `for` allows to write only once how the target folder is defined.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I solved it yesterday, just forgot to update the question with my answer. I think your solution is correct as well though.